# Find out how much time a process spent in it self

Tags: time, benchmark

The `time` command can be used to get an estimate of CPU time for a given job. However, it appears that its output includes the time spent in child processes. Is there a way to get the time spent in the parent process only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[getrusage(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage) offers `RUSAGE_SELF` or `RUSAGE_CHILDREN`; a calling shell could only use `RUSAGE_CHILDREN` which would include your process and also the children of that process. Therefore as Stéphane Chazelas points out *your* process would need to call `getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &usage)` *from within itself*, which if your process cannot be edited to do that would have to happen via some `LD_PRELOAD` trick.

Another option would be to use DTrace or here SystemTap type kernel profiling facilities to report usage at process exit time; the following reports *all* process exit values:

```
probe kprocess.exit {
    printf("%s[%d]: %s\n  %s\n  %s\n\n",
      execname(), pid(), cmdline_str(),
      task_time_string(),
      proc_mem_string()
    );
}
```

we could also profile a specific PID or executable name with appropriate code, here again with SystemTap:

```
probe kprocess.exit {
    if (pid() != target()) next;
    printf("%s[%d]: %s\n", execname(), pid(), task_time_string());
}
```

Though this may require extra testing to confirm what happens when a process is instead killed by signal, etc.

Comment: A (POSIX) shell can do those with the `times` special builtin, but here, you'd need the process being benchmarked to do that `getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF)` not the shell. The shell can't do it in its place, you'd need some LD_PRELOAD trick to trick the process to do it upon exit.

Comment: LD_PRELOAD did a good job. Checkout https://github.com/milasudril/benchmark